# how to replace a part of a string

Tags: mysql

I have a field that always consists of three values with dots between them.

like:

```
123456.22.aaa
23455.11.bbb
```

I would like to write a query that will update only the first part of the above field with a different value, so I will have them like:

```
111111.22.aaa
222222.11.bbb
```

That is - replace only the first part - up to the first dot of the field.
How can I get the first part out of this string?

note: there is no pattern for this value, I cannot search for a similar string and replace it. The only indication is that I need to replace the sub-string up to the first `.`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this very specific format, use `substring_index` with `-2` as the last parameter:

```
select concat('new value.', substring_index('123456.22.aaa', '.', -2))
-- new value.22.aaa
```